# Delete all data samples linked to a workout

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

When deleting a workout from the Health app that has other samples linked to it with [`HKHealthStore.healthStore.add(_:, to:, completion:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkhealthstore/1614165-add) you are prompted if you want to delete only the workout or also the linked data like in the screenshot below:

[image]

I'm trying to recreate the same functionality inside the app I'm building and I was wondering if there is a simple API to do this in a simple way.

Deleting only the workout can be done with a simple [`HKHealthStore.delete(_:,completion:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkhealthstore/1614155-delete) but I cannot find a way to load (or delete) all linked data all together. [`HKHealthStore.deleteObjects(of:, predicate:, withCompletion:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkhealthstore/1614162-deleteobjects) seems promising by passing a predicate created with [`HKQuery.predicateForObjects(from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkquery/1614773-predicateforobjects) but it seems you cannot specify a type that match any kind of object.

Is there a simple way to do this that I'm not seeing or I have to manually delete every object type I know I have linked to the workout?

Comment: Did you able to find a solution?

Comment: No, but I actually didn't actively search for one since, I juts put the feature on hold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to delete a workout and all the samples link to this workout.

You first need to fetch the workout you want to delete using an HKSampleQuery.
Once you fetched it.
You have no choice to save all the samples type that you can link to you workout. You can use a function, for instance:

```swift
private func samplesTypeLinkedToWorkout() -> [HKObjectType] {
        return [
            HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.heartRate)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.distanceWalkingRunning)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.distanceCycling)!,
            HKSeriesType.workoutRoute()
        ]
    }
```

Find all the HKSamples link to a workout by using HKQuery.predicateForObjects(from: HKWorkout) and delete them :

```swift
let workoutObjectsPredicate = HKQuery.predicateForObjects(from: workoutInHealthKit)
samplesTypeLinkedToWorkout().forEach {
    self.healthKitStore.deleteObjects(of: $0, predicate: workoutObjectsPredicate) { (_, _, _) in }
}
```

Once they are deleted you simply delete the workout using :

```swift
healthKitStore.delete(workoutInHealthKit) { (deleteSucceed, _) in
   completion(deleteSucceed)
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be correct. You're calling deleteObjects() passing as type *workout* plus the predicate, hence only workout objects linked to `workoutInHealthKit` will be deleted, not other data like calories and distance.

Comment: If you link the distance and calorie to the workout using func add(_ samples: [HKSample], to workout: HKWorkout, completion: @escaping (Bool, Error?) -> Void) they will be return by the predicate

Comment: That is correct, but `deleteObjects` has two conditions: an object must both match the predicate and be of the given type. Since you specify `HKObjectType.workoutType()` distance and calories won't match.

Comment: Thank you, I guess that's the only way as I feared

Comment: How to delete Excercise minutes data from the activity ring?

Comment: @pradipsutariya Excercise minutes in activity ring is not editable you can only read it